# Core3.1 IdentityServer4 WebAPI cannot find/read access_token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, webapi

So I've been trying to set up IdentityServer4, used several guides from PluralSight and public available guides.

I'm able to get everything working on Core2.1, but as soon as I try to build an IdentityServer4 on Core3.1 (with all latest releases of frameworks and EXACTLY the same configuration of the Core2.1 example), my webAPI cannot authorize the client application even though the token is present.

The WebAPI is a .NET4.x project, using the IdentityServer3.Contrib.AccessTokenValidation package.

IDP Startup Configuration (Same for Core2.1 and Core3.1 Projects):

```
services
   .AddIdentityServer()
   .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
   .AddTestUsers(SeedData.GetUsers())
   .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(SeedData.GetIdentityResources())
   .AddInMemoryApiResources(SeedData.GetApiResources())
   .AddInMemoryClients(SeedData.GetClients());
```

WebAPI Startup Configuration (IdentityServer3.Contrib.AccessTokenValidation)
Works for Core2.1 IdentityServer4, but not for Core3.1 IdentityServer4

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
   app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions() {
      Authority = "https://localhost:44314/",
      ClientId = "kpcwebapi",
      RequiredScopes = new[] { "kpcwebapi" },
   });
}
```

Client Application Configuration
Works for Core2.1 IdentityServer4, but not for Core3.1 IdentityServer4

```
services.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:44314/";
    options.ClientId = "testHybrid";
    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
    options.Scope.Add("openid"); 
    options.Scope.Add("profile"); 
    options.Scope.Add("kpcwebapi");
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.ClaimActions.Remove("amr");
    options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("sid");
    options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("idp");
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
       NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.GivenName,
       RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
    };    
});
```

I'm sure that the configuration is correct, as everything works perfectly on Core2.1
My question, as I can't find it myself, has anything changed in Core3.1 IdentityServer4 that my WebAPI doesn't work anymore? I'm starting to think there's a major bug/issue with the lastest release of IdentityServer4 (for Core3.1) ... since we're using OpenIDConnect ... Authorization should still work when updating your IdentityServer?

The funny thing is that when the API starts, I get an exception whenever the IDP isn't running, if it is running it passes the statement without errors/faults.
So my API really does establishe a connection to the IDP (both Core2.1 and Core3.1) but when it's the Core3.1 IDP, received calls from the client app are not authenticated/authorized.

If anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate sharing it as I've just lost 2 weeks of time trying to get it to work on Core3.1 ...

Answer (score -1):

For your WebApi, have you consider using IdentityServer4 library instead of IdentityServer3?

You can find the example here
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/stable/topics/apis.html

Comment: Yes we have considered that, but it doesn't work. IdentityServer4 is a .NET Core library while our API is a .NET 4.x project (because it uses our EntityFramework6 DbContext)